# On Redraw ListBox is not going to last entry

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-xe7

I have a listbox Initially set up in LiveBindings which shows a Bitmap Image, some Text (First line of a house address) and the detail text is the Postcode. When I initially run the program everything is fine, all the addresses in the Database Table show in the listbox. I then add an address and it is added to the bottom of the list. I should say my program redraws the Listbox at runtime when I add an address.
The added address is shown at the bottom of the listbox but I cannot access it. If I add more addresses I cannot access them either, the listbox stops where the original one was drawn to. I can see them but cannot access them - Any Ideas

Tried to add an image but seemingly need 10 reputation points duh

Comment: I assume it's firedac as well? What's goloing? You should add the relevant part of the code.

Comment: It could be VCL or FMX.

Comment: Are you adding new addresses into database or are you editing the ListBox contents manually?

Comment: I am adding new addresses into the database then I am redrawing the database to the Listbox (initially it was set up using live bindings). Perhaps I should think of merely adding the last entry to the database and add that last entry to the listbox rather than redrawing the whole thing. I am using Firedac and SQLte

Comment: I have changed my code to add the latest (Home address) to the database and then add the same information (which is collected by edit.text boxes) to the Listbox. If I add more in the same session I cannot access any of them. To let you understand, I initially set up the listbox and database using livebindings I connected the database address fields to Labels so when I scroll down through the listbox the labels are updated with the house address, when I get to the bottom of the listbox I can highlight the added items, but they are not updating the labels with the address. Hope that is clearer.

Comment: Is there some way to refresh the initial livebingings setup as I am adding the new information to the database a runtime refresh of livebindings would show everything.